Client Side JavaScript Expression In Oracle Apex Dynamic Action
I'm new to JavaScript and I want to write Client Side conditions as JavaScript Expression which contain IF GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 contains 'B' or '-' in it. and GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER14 = "VS"
FROM Table ARPEX_CURIOR_TBL THEN It should be true else false.
In other words, I need JavaScript expression as Client Side condition in the Dynamic action of Interactive Grid for the Column contains at least one of the characters in value, and value would be ('B','-')
I tried solutions from AI but not working.
Edit 1 -

Dynamic Action needs to fire on the Change of
"GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21"
The value of the column GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 should contain "B"
Or "-" in it where GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER14 = "VS" FROM Table
ARPEX_CURIOR_TBL then it should get saved properly otherwise it
should give an alert Message.
when the dynamic action fires Alert Message should display
Eg - If the column value of GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 is "CTXY-L"
then it should not fire an alert message as it contains "-" in it.
Eg - If the column value of GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 is "LDLBBY"
then it should not fire an alert message as it contains "B" in it
Eg - If the column value of GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CHAR21 is "DCXDDY"
then it should fire an alert message as it does not contain "B" or "-" in it


Please provide more details (update your question). When should this dynamic action fire ? Explain in English (not code) what needs to happen when the dynamic action fires.

Here is an example on sample table EMP. Use case is that on change of ENAME, a dynamic action is fired that checks if ename contains letter X. If it does, an alert is fired. The alert is only fired for records that have a JOB value of MANAGER.

Create editable IG on EMP table
Set the static id of the column JOB to JOB_COLUMN - this is needed to be able to reference this column in a javascript expression.
Create a dynamic action on Change of column ENAME. Make sure to set Event Scope to Dynamic since the report can be refreshed using Ajax callback.



Create a hidden page item to indicate if an ENAME value is considered "bad": P226_BAD_CHARACTERS
Add a true action of type "Execute Server-side Code" to check if the string contains X or x.



Add a true action of type "Alert" with a server-side condition of "Item=Value" and a client side condition of $v('JOB_COLUMN') == 'MANAGER'


To save the IG, add an action of type "Submit Page" with a similar serverside condition.
Note that this isn't the "standard" flow on an IG. Typically validations are fired for all rows at once on page submit, not in dynamic actions on single row change. With this implementation, a change is done for every row change.

Thanks a lot! It's working Properly now I just need JavaScript expression for WRITE  P60_ERROR_MESSAGE NOT EQUALS TO 'Y' AND GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER14 = 'US21' to fulfill 2 conditions on the client side.

why ? Just incorporate that as a serverside condition in your dynamic action

I'm not sure you can capture a row value in a javascript expression. How would javascript know which row you want the value for ? For page items see my updated answer

Server Side condition for Dynamic action or True Action Execute Server Side Code or on Alert? I tried to use Server side Condition "Expression" as :GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_NUMBER14 = 'US21' in all three areas but its not working

I got it to work and edited my answer. Please re-read in detail, some things have changed (static id of column). I used this blog as source

SORRY FOR LATE RESPONSE. YES IT WORKED PROPERLY. THANKS A LOT !

Consider marking the question as answered - no better way to say thanks here on stack overflow

apex.item("P52_ERROR_MESSAGE").getValue() != 'Y'
&& apex.item("P52_INPUT_BATCH_NUMBER").getValue() == 'US21' this is right client side condition if I'm using Items and not columns (Error message and input batch number)

Great to hear - happy to help
